# How to prevent data loss from redis where server is stopped forcefully which results in RedisCommandInterruptedException

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce

```
@Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate; 

public List<Object> getDataFromRedis(String redisKey) {
        
            try {
                
                long numberOfEntriesToRead = 60000;
                return stringRedisTemplate.executePipelined(
                        (RedisConnection connection) -> {
                            StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn =(StringRedisConnection)connection;
                            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfEntriesToRead; index++) {
                                stringRedisConn.lPop(redisKey);
                            }
                            return null;
                        });
            }catch (RedisCommandInterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Interrupted EXCEPTION :::", e);
            }
        } 
    }
```

I have a method which reads redis content for given key. Now the problem is when my application server is stopped while this method is trying to fetch data from redis i am getting RedisCommandInterruptedException exception which results in loss of some data from redis. So how can i overcome this problem Any suggestions are appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines are not atomic operations therefore there is no guarantee that all/none of the commands are executed when an exception happens.

You can use lua scripts or [multi command](https://redis.io/commands/multi) to make run operations in a single transaction.
You can read more about using multi in spring boot data redis in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148383/how-to-implement-redis-multi-exec-by-using-spring-data-redis) and this [site](https://github.com/eric-wu/dashboard/wiki/3.-Redis-Transactions-via-Spring-Data-Redis#optimistic-locking-using-watch-multi-and-exec).